# Query Elastic search from spark returns empty Map for values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch

When querying elastic search from Spark, only _id value is being fetched but not the any values.

Elastic search instance running in cloud. Trying to query from Spark running in my windows laptop

```
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
      .setMaster("local[*]")
      .setAppName("ElasticSearch Query")
      .set("es.nodes", "https://my-es-search.xyz.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com")
      .set("es.port", "443")
      .set("es.nodes.wan.only", "true")

    val spark = SparkSession.builder.config(sparkConf).getOrCreate()      
    val myRdd = spark.sparkContext.esRDD("my_order_index", "?q=*")
    myRdd.take(10).foreach(println)
```

Maven Dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-hadoop</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Actual Result:

```
(order-2019-05+2+1301,Map())
(order-2019-05+5+0,Map())
(order-2019-05+1+1283,Map())
(order-2019-05+1+1286,Map())
(order-2019-05+1+1285,Map())
(order-2019-05+3+1359,Map())
(order-2019-05+0+1236,Map())
(order-2019-05+0+1235,Map())
(order-2019-05+2+1297,Map())
(order-2019-05+6+2,Map())
```

When queried from Kibana, here is how a document looks like:

```
        "_index" : "my_order_index",
        "_type" : "order",
        "_id" : "order-2019-05+2+1301",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
                   "name":"John",
                   "orderValue":"1000.00" 
        }
```

My concern is why is the tuple Map is empty, only Map(). how can I fetch my document?
I even tried the same code in Java, result is exactly same, an Empty Map. However, I did enable debug mode in Java, I can see the queries executed behind the scenes , fetching all the columns.

Comment: What version of `elasticsearch` and `spark` are you using!, could you add that info please?

Comment: Looks to me that your field `orderValue` is `"1000"` instead of `1000`. I keep getting `NumberFormatException` when I'm trying to read it from local elastic into Spark using your code. **(Spark 2.4.0 ES 6.5.4 Scala 2.11.8)** . Could you try this and let me know if you have any luck `val myRdd = spark.sparkContext.esRDD("my_order_index/order", "?q=*", Map[String, String]("es.read.field.include"->"name"))`. If that runs you can probably replace `name` with `name, orderValue` and see if that works as well. Let me know your observations.

Comment: Thanks @kamal I just tried by passing an additional parameter to fetch only required column, it still didn't fetch any result.  returning same empty Map(). I also added my dependencies from POM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this issue (although once you've mentioned your pom, I was pretty sure what's wrong, I did spend time to reproduce it)

Notice the document that you have. It has `"_type": "order"` which means that the Elasticsearch that is being *queried to* is using a version prior to version **7.0.0**

Elasticsearch prior to **7.0.0** used to have a concept of [`type`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-type-field.html) which they've removed (as per this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/removal-of-types.html)) in version **7.0.0**.

Go to the browser and check what you observe in the field `number`  under the `version` section when you hit the below elasticsearch server you have:

https://my-es-search.xyz.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com

For e.g. when I hit my local elasticsearch instance (http://localhost:9200) in browser, I observe the below:

```
{
  "name" : "jqzqX5D",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "11YmK-ChT4OuXW8Mb9t9tw",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.5.4",                    <------- Notice this. That is Elasticsearch version that is being used. 
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "d2ef93d",
    "build_date" : "2018-12-17T21:17:40.758843Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.5.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

You would need to update your pom file to use the same version of `elasticsearch-hadoop`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-hadoop</artifactId>
        <version>6.5.4</version>                     <------- Change this. 
    </dependency>
```

You should be able to see values appearing in your Map once you do that.

Hope it helps and feel free to accept the answer and upvote it if you think it helped!!

Comment: perfect Mr. Kamal . changing the version did the trick. Really appreciate your quick and exact solution. I did upvote, But this is just my second question on stackoverflow, don't have enough reputation. Sorry and Thank you.

Comment: ha ha!! do come back and upvote/accept when you can!! ;) Glad I could help you!!